# Configure database pooling on a SQL Server database via connection string?

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string

Connecting to a SQL Server 2016 DB from C# I have a connection string like:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MyNewDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30
```

This was generated automatically by VS and implies I can enable connection-pooling via the connection string but I am unclear whether this is configuring the driver or the database, to know where to find documentation.

What pool-related options are available and how can I use them to enable connection pooling transparently to my application? I assume there is more to it than just `Pooling=true`

Comment: Assuming you are using the `SqlClient` driver, the connection pooling connection string parameters are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring). Note that each ADO.NET data provider may implement connection pooling differently but the overall concept is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, ADO.NET connection pooling is based on reusing the same connection string over and over again, by default it is set to true. So just omit `Pooling=False` and you are good to go.

Comment: That's useful to know. DB drivers are an area I really know very little about, is ADO.NET the default .Net connection?

Comment: @Mr.Boy no, ADO.NET is the name of the API that all connections implement; the default SQL Server client *used* to be `System.Data.SqlClient`, but more recently there's also `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - same thing conceptually, but packaged slightly differently and more up to date. It is largely up to you whether to use `System.Data.SqlClient` or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`